# plotting contour, stream and quiver plots using x,y,z position and vx,vy,vz particle velocities

Tags: python, matplotlib, stream, contour, particles

I have a set of particles with x,y,z and vx,vx,vz and I want to plot a stream, contour and quiver plot to visualize their motion. e.g. arrows indicating direction of vx, vy, vz where magnitude of that location is defined by local speed of particles, their position specified by x,y,z (so one plot with x-pos vs y-pos with the quivers/contours/streams indicating their velocities). I can just go with 2D to start as I'm doing xy,yz,xz projections separately and are degenerate with the 2D solution if you can help. There is nice example of exactly what I would like [here](https://pynbody.github.io/pynbody/tutorials/pictures.html#velocity-vectors) but I don't have access to this tool.

[image]

An example of my x,y and vx,vy are:

```
x = [-0.00273269 -0.01065061 -0.00043434 ...,  0.09494386  0.09479769]

y = [ 0.01634852 -0.00807868 -0.00833457 ...,  0.07971196  0.0834935]

vx = [ 45.82292815   27.16221568   12.9619711  ...,  128.62980572    138.51976486]

vy = [ 44.11188404   21.35615525  -25.9338436  ...,   31.25305638   32.37035995]
```

My terrible attempt:

```
img_width = 300
vector_resolution = 40

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-img_width / 2, img_width / 2, img_width / vector_resolution),
       np.arange(-img_width / 2, img_width / 2, img_width / vector_resolution))

vx = np.histogram(vx,bins=vector_resolution-1)[1]
vy = np.histogram(vy,bins=vector_resolution-1)[1]
vz = np.histogram(vz,bins=vector_resolution-1)[1]

ax.quiver(X, Y, vx, vy, color='black', edgecolor='black')
```

This however doesn't seem to overlay the quiver marks where they should be, possibly because I'm using the wrong method.

I also tried a stream plot:

```
ax.streamplot(X, Y, vx, vy, density=0.6, color='k', linewidth=2)
```

but I am getting shape errors. I'm aiming for the kind of example on the [Matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/streamplot_demo_features.html).

I tried contours:

```
Z = ml.griddata(vx, vy, vz, X, Y,interp='linear')

ax.contour(X,Y,Z, 15, linewidths = 0.5, colors = 'k')
```

For this I'm aiming for something like the [contour example here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) with a colorbar indicating speed.
The above doesn't provide meaningful results however. Are there any nice modules out there which convert say particle data of this kind into the required binned components for quiver, stream and contour plots? Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided examples definitions of your `vx, vy, vz` arrays. Also, I don't understand why you redefine these variables using `np.histogram`.

Comment: I have added an example. I redefine them because I thought I had to cast the vxs,vys into a an array which is the length of the mesh being used for the quivers.

Comment: I don't think histogram is doing what you want. If these variables are not originally on a structured grid people often interpolate the data onto one (e.g. see scipy.interpolate.interp2d or scipy.interpolate.griddata).